# DnD 4e Warden's Grasp Range

Tags: dnd-4e, triggered-actions, warden

The range of the power is Close Burst 5 and triggers when the marked target attacks any ally other than the warden themself. I know you must be in that range to mark the target, do you need to remain within that range for it to trigger the interrupt as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be within 5 squares of the target *when* the attack happens — not because of the Close Burst 5 line, but because of the Trigger line:

> **Trigger:** An enemy marked by you that is within 5 squares of you makes an attack that does not include you as a target

If they're more than 5 squares away, they won't satisfy the trigger. If they're within 5 squares of range, you can then use your power, which is a Close Burst 5, which is a range chosen because it's perfect for reaching anyone who could trigger this power.

Now, it looks like you may be confused about some other stuff, which I'll address:

- *"trigger the interrupt"* - Warden's Grasp is an immediate reaction, not an immediate interrupt. See PHB 268 for the difference between these two. This is important, because it means that if the attack also lets the creature *move out of range from you,* you won't be able to use your grasp on them. (Kobold Skirmisher monsters might have such a power, if I remember correctly.)
- *"I know you must be in that range [of close burst 5] to mark the target"* - I'm not sure what you're referring to there. Mark range is unrelated to this power. With the normal Warden you'll usually be marking with their Nature's Wrath feature, which marks adjacent enemies until the end of your next turn. Then, if one of them attacks someone other than you, they're marked and you can respond to that with Warden's Grasp.
- *"do you need to remain within that range"* - Just to be clear, you don't need to *remain* in range forever. You can walk over 5 squares away then come back. You just need to make sure you're back within 5 squares of your enemy when they perform the attack if you want this power to trigger.